# Using elements of a list as SparseArray patterns: "can't be used as part specification"

Tags: sparse-arrays, rule

I don't have much experience with `SparseArray`, and the search here did not give me an answer to this.

I'm trying to numerically compute a certain spectrum, and the method creates a tridiagonal matrix. Using `SparseArray` to create the matrix$^*$ makes the computation run many times faster, and the result is correct, however Mathematica gives out warnings:

```
Part::pkspec1: The expression -1+mr cannot be used as a part specification.
Part::pkspec1: The expression -1+mr cannot be used as a part specification.
Part::pkspec1: The expression -1+mr cannot be used as a part specification.
General::stop: Further output of Part::pkspec1 will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

$^*$ I say "to create the matrix", because I need a large number of Eigenvalues, so Mathematica converts the matrix to a dense one anyway.

```
    Nr = 1500;(*Number of grid points*)
    R = 150;(*Size of grid*)
    hr = N[R/Nr, 10];(*Grid step*)
    B = 0;(*Parameter*)
    Anr = Table[N[Sqrt[1 - 1/2/nr], 10], {nr, 1, Nr + 1}];
(*Precomputed values for the matrix start*)
    Fgs[nr_] := Exp[-2 nr hr];
    Bnr = Table[
       N[2 + 1/hr^2 - 
         1/2 (Anr[[nr]] Fgs[nr - 1] + Anr[[nr + 1]] Fgs[nr + 1])/Fgs[nr]/
           hr^2, 10], {nr, 1, Nr}];
    Bnr0 = N[2 + 1/hr^2 - 1/2 Sqrt[1/2]*Fgs[1]/hr^2, 10];
    Bnr[[Nr]] = N[2 + 1/hr^2 - 1/2 Anr[[Nr]]*Fgs[Nr - 1]/Fgs[Nr]/hr^2, 10];
    Hmm = Table[N[1/hr^2 - Bnr[[mr]] + 1/8 B^2 mr^2 hr^2], {mr, 1, Nr}];
    Hnm1 = Table[N[-1/2 Anr[[mr]]/hr^2], {mr, 1, Nr}];
    Hnm2 = Table[N[-1/2 Anr[[mr + 1]]/hr^2], {mr, 1, Nr}];
(*Precomputed values for the matrix end*)
    Hnm = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> N[1/hr^2 - Bnr0], {2, 1} -> 
         N[-1/2 Sqrt[1/2]/hr^2], {mr_, mr_} -> 
         Hmm[[mr - 1]], {nr_, mr_} /; nr - mr == -1 -> 
         Hnm1[[mr - 1]], {nr_, mr_} /; nr - mr == 1 -> 
         Hnm2[[mr - 1]]}, {Nr + 1, Nr + 1}, 0];(*Creating the matrix*)
    T1 = AbsoluteTiming[Hnm = Normal[Hnm];
       {En, Cn} = Eigensystem[Hnm]];(*Eigensystem*)
    T1[[1]]
    g = N[1/10, 10];(*Broadening*)
    Cl = Table[Cn[[l, 1]]^2, {l, 1, Length[En]}];
    HiIm = Table[{w, g Total[Cl/(g^2 + (w - En)^2)]}, {w, -5, 15, 0.05}];
(*Computing the spectrum*)
    ListPlot[HiIm, ScalingFunctions -> "Log", Joined -> True, ImageSize -> Large]
```

As a result, I get a very good time (I measure only the time to solve for Eigensystem, because creating the matrix itself takes way less time):

`0.535721`

And a correct looking plot:

[image]

> How do I correctly define the Sparse Array, if I need to use a list of pre-computed values? Why does Mathematica give out warnings in this case, but still gives a correct result?

This is just a model problem, I need to understand how to work here so I can solve the more complicated cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `RuleDelayed` instead of simply `Rule`. No error if you modify your code like this:

```
Hnm=SparseArray[{
    {1,1}->N[1/hr^2-Bnr0],{2,1}->N[-1/2 Sqrt[1/2]/hr^2],
    {mr_,mr_}:>Hmm[[mr-1]],
    {nr_,mr_}/;nr-mr==-1:>Hnm1[[mr-1]],
    {nr_,mr_}/;nr-mr==1:>Hnm2[[mr-1]]},
    {Nr+1,Nr+1},0];
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 3):

Vitaliy has already given complete answer to your question. I would just like to add as an extended comment that using patterns in `SparseArray` creation comes at a certain cost, in particular if the values to write are already precomputed. Whenever you want to fill diagonals of a matrix, it is a good idea to use `Band` instead.

Here is Vitaliy's solution:

```
A = SparseArray[{
       {1, 1} -> N[1/hr^2 - Bnr0], 
       {2, 1} -> N[-1/2 Sqrt[1/2]/hr^2], 
       {mr_, mr_} :> Hmm[[mr - 1]], 
       {nr_, mr_} /; nr - mr == -1 :> Hnm1[[mr - 1]], 
       {nr_, mr_} /; nr - mr == 1 :> Hnm2[[mr - 1]]}, 
       {Nr + 1, Nr + 1}, 0.]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.012

And here is the same using `Band`:

```
B = SparseArray[
     {
      {1, 1} -> N[1/hr^2 - Bnr0], 
      {2, 1} -> N[-1/2 Sqrt[1/2]/hr^2],
      Band[{2, 2}] -> Hmm,
      Band[{1, 2}] -> Hnm1,
      Band[{3, 2}] -> Most@Hnm2
      },
     {Nr + 1, Nr + 1}, 0.]; // RepeatedTiming // First
```

> 0.0027

Checking the correctness:

```
A == B
```

> True

Comment: Thank you very much! I have read about Band, but all the examples listed are constants, and I didn't know how to use a list

Comment: You're welcome.